# Subscript out of Range used in a For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

Running the following code in VBA to call excel cells in an array and use it in FOR loop for calculation but getting "Subscript out of Range" error

```
Sub nestedLoopFor()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim Qty As Variant


    Dim Cap As Variant
      Qty = Range("C2:L2").Value 'call cells from 3rd row
      Cap = Range("B3:B7").Value 'call cells from 2nd column

      For i = 1 To 5
          For j = 1 To 10
          Cells(i + 2, j + 2).Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(Qty(j), Cap(i))
          Qty(j) = Qty(j) - Cells(i + 2, j + 2).Value
          Cap(i) = Cap(i) - Cells(i + 2, j + 2).Value
          Next
      Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: *Where* is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI Qty and Cap are 2-D arrays, so you need to provide both indexes if you want to access an element in one of them.

```
Cap(i, 1)
Qty(1, j)
```